# Android custom adapter listView looping more

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I am trying to create a custom adapter for my `listView`. Here is my `CustomAdapter` class-

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Custom>{
private ArrayList<Custom> entries;
private Activity activity;
private int height;

public CustomAdapter(int hei, Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Custom> entries) {
    super(a, textViewResourceId, entries);
    this.entries = entries;
    this.activity = a;
    this.height=hei;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView item1;
    public ImageView image;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
            (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.review_list_m, null);
        v.setMinimumHeight(height);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.item1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.posterView);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

    final Custom custom = entries.get(position);
    if (custom != null) {
        String imgUrl=custom.getImage();
        Log.v("PATH",custom.getcustomBig()); 
        holder.item1.setText(custom.getcustomBig());

    }
    return v;
 }

}
```

Then I entered only two values in customclass.
But the following line log in 6 times

```
Log.v("PATH",custom.getcustomBig());
```

Something like following

```
01-09 11:49:34.683: V/PATH(12629): Name 1
01-09 11:49:34.683: V/PATH(12629): Name 2
01-09 11:49:34.683: V/PATH(12629): Name 1
01-09 11:49:34.683: V/PATH(12629): Name 2
01-09 11:49:34.683: V/PATH(12629): Name 1
01-09 11:49:34.683: V/PATH(12629): Name 2
```

But showing only 2 entries in listView.

Anything weird ? Because I need to implement download image script on `listView`. In that case will that image get downloaded more than 1 times ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code : (Don't make `custom` final and don't check for `null`)

```
    Custom custom = entries.get(position);
    String imgUrl=custom.getImage();
    Log.v("PATH",custom.getcustomBig()); 
    holder.item1.setText(custom.getcustomBig());
```

Comment: tried this. but now also showing same. I tried Log.v("Position","-"+position); Then 0 and 1 is printing simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the entries list you are passing to the Constructor. getView() would be called for the number of items in the entries list. It might be possible that your entries list contains 6 values.